# How do I Update Kendo UI Pro

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am new to Kendo UI and I have an application using Kendo UI Pro.

I see some JS files and css files included in project. Now I want to upgrade kendo UI. I have intalled Kendo UI client on my machine and logged in with my email and password.

What is next step? Do I need to browse my project file or I need to download files and manually replace?

Comment: not a relevant question on this forum probably

Answer (score 1):

See [Installation Instructions](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/introduction).

The Telerik UI for ASP.NET MVC contains the following important directories.

1. js - minified JavaScript files.
2. styles - minified CSS files and images
3. wrappers\aspnetmvc\Binaries\MVC5 - assemblies for ASP.NET MVC 5 applications.

To update an existing installation do this:

1. Copy Kendo UI CSS resources to the content folder of your project.
2. Copy Kendo UI JavaScript resources to the Scripts folder of your project.
3. If you use it, copy the Kendo.Mvc.dll to your project and re-reference the dll.